# Android studio falsely displays errors after analyze

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Android studio 4.2 Beta 4 falsely displays errors inside the editor when this is none. For example it displays as error the sequences' function `find` or the Strings' function `isNullOrEmpty`.

But the build works as expected and on the Stable version of the android studio I do not have those highlight issues.

I have tried:

- Deleting the studio's folder
- Deleting users/user/.android
- Deleting users/user/.gradle
- Deleting project's .idea folder
- Invalidating caches

[image]

Do you have any suggestions? I am running Windows 10 (20H2 Build 19042.746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After visiting the [Configure Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#windows) page I got the idea to delete the following folder and everything works as expected now:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio
```